# GJR-GARCH model with exogenous regressors in R is wrong

Tags: r

I want to estimate the impact of news on the stock returns volatility. I regard the existence of news as 1 and 0 thereafter, the news (`28`) is very few compared to the stock returns (`2274`).

I conduct the `GJR-GARCH` model as following:

```
spec.gjrgarch=ugarchspec(variance.model =
 list(model="gjrGARCH",garchOrder=c(1,1),external.regressors=QE1),mean.model
     = list(armaOrder=c(0, 0), include.mean=T, archm=F,arfima=F), distribution.model="std")
     d.gjrfit=ugarchfit(spec = spec.gjrgarch,data=DJILR) Error in temp$h : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors In addition: Warning
 message: In .makefitmodel(garchmodel = "gjrGARCH", f = .gjrgarchLLH, T
     = T,  :  rugarch-->warning: failed to invert hessian
```

What's the meaning of the warnings? Does it mean, there is no necessary to conduct this model? The impact of news cannot be measured in this model?
Someone can help me?

Thank you very much in advance! Greatly appreciate!

Comment: very few news and very large number of returns

Answer (score 0):

redefine the QE1 such as:
QE1=as.matrix(q1,q2,q3)
then the process can be conducted.